# Animating a Path in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to animate a path using Android's Canvas and PathMeasure. On each frame, the path should draw a path segment from a source path until the entire segment is complete. The resulting effect should be similar to writing with a pen/pencil/etc. However, when I use PathMeasure getSegment, the destination path doesn't seem to draw anything.

The following code should draw the source path in gray, the termination point of the current segment in red, and finally the path sub segment in black, however only the source path and termination point are drawn (the segment is not).

```
public void initialize() {

    // Path to animate
    source = new Path();
    source.moveTo(0f, 10f);
    source.quadTo(100, 10, 100, 100);

    // temp path to store drawing segments
    segment = new Path();

    pm = new PathMeasure(source, false);

    frames = 10;
    increment = pm.getLength() / (float)frames;
    Log.d(TAG, "increment " + increment);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

    black = new Paint(paint);
    black.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    gray = new Paint(paint);
    gray.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    red = new Paint(paint);
    red.setColor(Color.RED);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);

    // draw the source path
    c.drawPath(source, gray);

    // draw the segment
    segment.reset();
    pm.getSegment(0, d, segment, true);
    c.drawPath(segment, black);

    //RectF bounds = new RectF();
    //segment.computeBounds(bounds, true);
    //Log.d(TAG, "bounds: " + bounds.toString());

    // draw the termination point on the segment
    float[] pos = new float[2];
    float[] tan = new float[2];
    pm.getPosTan(d, pos, tan);
    c.drawPoints(pos, red);

    // update the frame index
    frameIndex = (frameIndex + 1) % frames;
    d = (float)frameIndex * increment;
    Log.d(TAG, "d = " + d);

}
```

Comment: Just for fun, can we see the logcat output?

Comment: I haven't used `Path` or `PathMeasure` before, but my hunch is that the entire quadratic is considered a "segment", so if your distance doesn't encapsulate the whole thing it doesn't get returned. What's the return value of the `getSegment` call?

Comment: The logcat output is as you would expect. 'd' is incremented based on the length of the segment and if you uncomment the bounds code, you get the correct bounds on what would have been the path.

The return value of getSegment is true. In fact it will always be true as long as the start and end distance parameters are not reversed (0 <= d) and are between 0 and pm.getLength(). You can check SkPathMeasure.cpp in the SKIA library to confirm this.

I believe I've tried doing a getSegment with 0 to getLength and still received an "invisible" path.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding rlineto(0,0) to the segmented path and then draw the path using paint.Documentation suggest this to be used with android versions lesser than 4.3.This solution will apply only if your target sdk is less than or equal to 4.3.